# Polymer: styling paper-input

Tags: javascript, polymer, styling

I would like to style some properties of a paper-input element. So I tried:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <style>
        :host {
            --paper-input-container-label: #fff;
            --paper-input-container-label-focus: #fff;
        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <paper-input-container>
            <label>My Label</label>
            <input is="iron-input" value="{{someval}}">
        </paper-input-container>
    </template>
    ...
```

As far as I understand you cannot style

```
<paper-input .... ></paper-input>
```

and you have to use `paper-input-container`, right ?

Anyway,the styling options applied above nothing gets actually styled. But, when I, for example, use

```
--paper-input-container-color: #fff;
```

it does work (but is not what I want). Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`paper-input`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container) provides several possibilities to style it. Some css parameters are simple values - such as your `--paper-input-container-color`. Others – like `--paper-input-container` are mixins where you can adjust anything you want. To re-define your mixin see the docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-css-mixins).

What is also very helpful is to have a look at your page's header where all the custom styles are applied. For instance search for the element `<style scope="paper-input-container"></style>` and have a look what is being defined by polymer and how these styles are applied. If you add your own `<style>` element in your template it will be somewhere in the `<head>` and take care how the css selectors are transformed.

Hope these explanations lead you your way to achieve what you want...

Comment: That did the trick. Digging around in the styles/head did indeed help, but I think some good documentation on this subject will make it a lot easier :)